# cassandra 1.2 fails to init snappy in freebsd

Tags: cassandra, snappy

```
ERROR [WRITE-/10.10.35.30] 2013-06-19 23:15:56,907 CassandraDaemon.java (line 175) Exception in thread Thread[WRITE-/10.10.35.30,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
    at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:341)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:143)
```

When going through know issues i found this
The native library snappy-1.0.4.1-libsnappyjava.so for Snappy compression is included in the snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar file. When the JVM initializes the JAR, the library is added to the default temp directory. If the default temp directory is mounted with a noexec option, it results in the above exception.

i added JVM_OPTS=-Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/tmp   in cassandra.in.sh  and it still didnot work.
i also tried specifying the temp directory directly

```
./bin/cassandra -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/tmp
```

On the same machine cassandra version 1.0.12 works fine.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the thing on single node? If so can go to cassandra.yaml and change  internode_compression to none and restart the server

Comment: I had the same problem on RHEL5.9 when running integration tests with EmbeddedCassandra, but the fix suggested by abhi did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that there is no FreeBSD library included in the snappy JAR file that comes with Cassandra. Install the archivers/snappy-java port, delete the snappy-java JAR file that came with Cassandra, and copy /usr/local/share/java/classes/snappy-java.jar into Cassandra's lib directory.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem happened when trying to enable snappy compression for apache kafka 0.8 on FreeBSD but the solution was the same. Just copy `/usr/local/share/java/classes/snappy-java.jar` to the `kafka/src/core/target/scala-2.8.0` directory, restart kafka and enjoy!